# How can I have an Akka actor executed every 5 min?

Tags: akka

I'd like to know if there are any mechanism in Akka that can have an actor executed periodically?

Comment: Here I just found a perfect solution: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/scheduler.html

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You don't really need an actor to do this in Akka 1.3.1 you can schedule a function to be called every 5 minutes like this:

```
Scheduler.schedule(() => println("Do something"), 0L, 5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

However, if you do want it to be an actor for other reasons you would call it like this

```
case class Message()

val actor = actorOf(new Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Message() => println("Do something in actor")
  }
}).start()

Scheduler.schedule(actor, Message(), 0L, 5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

If you're using Akka 2.0 then it would be done like this

```
val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")
system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 5 minutes)(println("do something"))
```

Or send a message to an actor every 5 minutes like this

```
case class Message()
class MyActor extends Actor {
  def receive = { case Message() => println("Do something in actor") }
}

val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")
val actor = system.actorOf(Props(new MyActor), name = "actor")
system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 5 minutes, actor, Message())
```

Comment: Scheduler.schedule doesn't appear to exist anymore

Comment: keep in mind that you may want to know that the previous invocation finished its course before the new one fires after 5 minutes, in some cases at least. You might use `scheduleOnce` with some extra logic, for that.

Comment: If you want to do this from within the Actor itself, you can call `context.system.scheduler.schedule(<params>)` to do your scheduling work

Answer (score 22):

The approach using schedule is one good approach, although there is a potential for the messages to queue up if the work done on schedule is so great that it might take longer than the scheduled interval. If you want the interval to occur between the *end* of one iteration and the *beginning* of the next, then use `scheduleOnce` with the following pattern:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class SchedulingActor extends Actor {

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    self ! "Do Some Work"
  }

  def receive = {
    case "Do Some Work" => 
      doWork
      context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(5 minutes, self, "Do Some Work")
  }

  def doWork = ???
}
```

Comment: This is the relevant answer as of 2016. Scheduler.schedule is no longer a valid method.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `context.system.scheduler.schedule(...)` to send messages to `self` every 5 mins? It would look much cleaner and eliminate need for overriding `preStart`.

Comment: @BranislavLazic No, the whole point of not setting a recurring schedule is to avoid sending another message to the actor if there is ever a situation in which the processing logic requires time beyond the interval between each scheduled message. With scheduleOnce(), the actor can take as long as it needs to in order complete whatever work is needed, and then when it is safe, setup another schedule to send a future message to itself. For some situations, this can avoid deadlocks and other concurrency issues.

Answer (score 3):

More complete Java example:

```
import akka.actor.AbstractActor;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class AnActor extends AbstractActor {
    private final FiniteDuration SCHEDULED_WORK_DELAY = new FiniteDuration(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    @Override
    public void preStart() {
        getSelf().tell("Do Scheduled Work", ActorRef.noSender());
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
        .matchEquals("Do Scheduled Work", work -> {
            doScheduledWork();
         context().system().scheduler().scheduleOnce(SCHEDULED_WORK_DELAY, getSelf(),
                "Do Scheduled Work", context().dispatcher(), ActorRef.noSender());
        })
        .build();
    }

    private void doScheduledWork() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone want java code then they can do like this

```
    Cancellable cancellable = system.scheduler().schedule(Duration.Zero(), Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES), cronActor, "tick", system.dispatcher(), null);
```