# Akka Actor Retry on Failure

Tags: scala, akka

I have an Actor that gets a message called Init and upon receiving this message, it tries to create a connection to an external service. Now this connection could succeed or fail and I know this information in my Actor:

```
def receive = {
  case Init => {
    val someConn: Option[Connection] = createConnection(...)
    someConn match {
      case Some(conn) => {
        // do something
      }
      case None => // I want to re-try Init, but after a few seconds delay!
  }
}
```

Upon None, I would like to send a self message to this actor with an Init message again, but I would not like to do it immediately. I would like to have a delay of few seconds, say 10 seconds. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send a message to yourself once, on a delay, using `scheduleOnce`, see my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31658345/5142537

```
context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10 seconds, self, Init)
```